# Generate EC Sales List for UK VAT Return

Tags: tax, reports, vat, b2b

We've just recently switched over to Magento and it's been working very well. As we reach the end of the VAT period, however, I'm struggling to figure out how to generate the necessary reports. Specifically, the EC sales list.

We need a report that lists the VAT IDs of EU B2B customers and their total spend during the period. I can't see any way to do this in Magento, and a Google search comes up with absolutely nothing on the subject.

There must be many UK-based Magento systems running that routinely need to generate this information, so it must be possible. Any idea how I do this?

Comment: As you know Magento does not have this feature built in. You will need a custom module/script that extracts all customers with a VAT ID and then calculates their total sales for the given period. It's a fairly straight forward job for a Magento developer.

Comment: I realise that it's possible to write something to do this. The point is that there must be very many sites in the UK that already have to do this - it's a legal requirement. I find it hard to believe that they've all individually created their own custom extension to do exactly the same thing. I was hoping to find an existing solution rather than have to spend my weekend figuring out how to write a reporting extension.

Comment: I have a general Magento export script that I use for various data exports, it can export customer lifetime sales, so might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote my own extension. I'd not done any (non-trivial) Magento development before, so I figured this was as good a place to start as any.

(TL,DR: It's on [github](https://github.com/dopiaza/magento-ec-sales-list))

As ever, once you dig a little deeper into the requirements, there's a little more to it than at first appearance. The VAT is charged (or not charged) based on the shipping address, so I need to check for a valid VAT ID there, rather than in the customer model. 
So, this is what I did.

First, I get all the invoices using a join on the shipping address table where I check the invoice creation date and check that the `vat_is_valid` flag is set and that the `vat_id` is not null.

```
$from = $this->getFrom()->format('Y-m-d');
$to = $this->getTo()->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection $invoices */
$invoices = \Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")
    ->getCollection()
    ->join(array(
        'shipping_address'=> 'order_address'),
        'shipping_address.entity_id = main_table.shipping_address_id',
        array('shipping_address.vat_id', 'shipping_address.vat_is_valid'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $from))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => $to))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_address.vat_id', array('notnull' => true))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_address.vat_is_valid', 1)
    ;
```

Now, that query uses the invoice date. Apparently, according to HMRC, the EC sales need to be included based on order date, not payment date (even if you are using cash accounting). Almost all our sales use Paypal Express so the order date and invoice date are the same, so that's not an immediate problem, but is something I should fix when I get chance.

Next, I need to take account of credit memos issued in the same period. Note that a credit memo may be issued in a different tax period to the invoice that is being credited.

```
$from = $this->getFrom()->format('Y-m-d');
$to = $this->getTo()->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Creditmemo_Collection $creditMemos */
$creditMemos = \Mage::getModel("sales/order_creditmemo")
    ->getCollection()
    ->join(array(
        'shipping_address'=> 'order_address'),
        'shipping_address.entity_id = main_table.shipping_address_id',
        array('shipping_address.vat_id', 'shipping_address.vat_is_valid'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $from))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => $to))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_address.vat_id', array('notnull' => true))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_address.vat_is_valid', 1)
;
```

Finally, I add up all of the invoice amounts for each VAT ID, deduct all the credit memos for that VAT ID and then output the result.

I'm pretty sure that all works as it should. I guess I'll find out soon enough as our VAT return has to go in this month :-)

Currently, this list is generated from the command line. Next, I'll be looking at how to build a proper Magento report so it can be easily generated from the Magento backend.

The full code is available on [github](https://github.com/dopiaza/magento-ec-sales-list).

Answer (score 0):

I put the code below into a module that might help as a starting block to getting the data you need.

The module will add a new menu item Sales->Customer Sales by VAT ID. The date ranges are configured in app/code/community/PAJ/Customersales/Helper/Data.php

Download the module here

https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-customersales/

These are the functions used in the module

This will get your customer collection

```
    public function getCustomerByVATID($_storeID=0)
{

    $_collection = \Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('taxvat');

    $_result = array();
    foreach ($_collection as $_customer) {
        $_result[] = $_customer->toArray();
    }



    return $_result

}
```

and this will get the total sales by date

```
    public function getCustomerSales($_customerId,$fromDate,$toDate)
{


    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate));

    $orderCollection = \Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('customer_id', $_customerId)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
        ->setOrder('created_at', \Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ;
    $numberOfOrders = $orderCollection->count();
    $newestOrder = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();

    $orderCollection->clear()->getSelect()
        ->columns(array('total_sales'=>'SUM(main_table.base_grand_total)'))
        ->group('customer_id')
    ;
    $totalSales = $orderCollection->getFirstItem()
        ->getData('total_sales');       

    return array('customersales' => $totalSales);

}
```

Then you export the data like this with the date range you want

```
    $fromDate='2015-01-01';
    $toDate='2015-02-01';

    foreach ($_collection as $_customer)
    {
        if (strlen($_customer['taxvat']) > 2)
        {

            $_sales=$_obj->getCustomerSales($_customer['entity_id'],$fromDate,$toDate);

            if($_sales['customersales'] > 0)
            {
                echo 'id ->'. $_customer['entity_id']. ' - '. $_customer['taxvat']. ' sales= '. $_sales['customersales']. "\n";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for those snippets - they look like a useful starting point. I'll try putting something together - I suspect I'm going to come out of this weekend knowing rather more about magenta internals than I started with...

Comment: I put my code into a basic module which might be of use to you, github link is in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's always useful to see other people's code. I've actually been working on my own solution - I'll post more details here later.